# How to remove elements of array in place returning the removed elements

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array `arr`. I want to destructively remove elements from `arr` based on a condition, returning the removed elements.

```
arr = [1,2,3]  
arr.some_method{|a| a > 1} #=> [2, 3]
arr #=> [1]
```

My first try was `reject!`:

```
arr = [1,2,3]  
arr.reject!{|a| a > 1}
```

but the returning blocks and `arr`'s value are both `[1]`.

I could write a custom function, but I think there is an explicit method for this. What would that be?

#### Update after the question was answered:

`partition` method turns out to be useful for implementing this behavior for hash as well. How can I remove elements of a hash, returning the removed elements and the modified hash?

```
hash = {:x => 1, :y => 2, :z => 3}
comp_hash, hash = hash.partition{|k,v| v > 1}.map{|a| Hash[a]}
comp_hash #=> {:y=>2, :z=>3}
hash #=> {:x=>1}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use `partition` here. It doesn't modify `self` inplace, but returns two new arrays. By assigning the second array to `arr` again, it gets the results you want:

```
comp_arr, arr = arr.partition { |a| a > 1 }
```

See the [documentation of partition](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition).

Answer (score 1):

All methods with a trailing bang `!` modify the receiver and it seems to be a convention that these methods return the resulting object because the non-bang do so.
What you can to do though is something like this:

```
b = (arr.dup - arr.reject!{|a| a>1 })
b # => [2,3]
arr #=> [1]
```

Here is a link to a [ruby styleguide](https://github.com/styleguide/ruby) which has a section on nameing - although its rather short

Answer (score 0):

To remove (in place) elements of array returning the removed elements one could use delete method, as per [Array class documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-delete):

```
a = [ "a", "b", "b", "b", "c" ]
a.delete("b")                   #=> "b"
a                               #=> ["a", "c"]
a.delete("z")                   #=> nil
a.delete("z") { "not found" }   #=> "not found"
```

It accepts block so custom behavior could be added, as needed

Comment: `delete` doesn't allow specify a condition (a > 1) and – as shown in your example – it also only returns the last deleted item, even if multiple items have been removed.